# Does bot connector service support Mutual TLS verification?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I want to know  whether bot connector service(Microsoft botframework) supports Mutual TLS or not? I want to verify the source of the events coming from bot connector service. I am not able to find any documentation which clearly specifies about mTLS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All communications between the bot and the Bot Connector service utilize SSL/TLS for authentication. SSL/TLS connections adhere to the `x.509v3` certificate protocol for identifying all HTTPS services (see [Authentication with the Bot Connector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)).

You can read more about the Azure Bot Service's Data Protection protocol by reading this doc, [Encrypt sensitive information in transit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Additionally, [What data is encrypted?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-encryption?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#what-data-is-encrypted) can provide additional insight.